# Import Excel to DataTable string's are empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, import, dataset

To import excel to datatable, I am using the simple code:

```
string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", physicalFolder + FileUpload1.FileName);
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", connectionString);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

When in one of the rows of excel, if my row looks like below

[image]

strings are ommited and my data set looks like this

[image]

However if I add some strings and if my upload looks like this:

[image]

Then my dataset looks like it does not omit the strings:

[image]

Comment: I was also facing the same issue. Then i manually changed the datatype of that particular column in excel from general to text. And it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the provider decides on the type of the column from first row of the column (the row after the header row). When first row contains a number, the type of column is `double` or another number type, so it cannot contain string values.

I tried every possible way (setting the table structure beforehand, using a `DataReader`, changing the format of the cell, ...) and they all failed. It seem to be the problem with `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB` provider. I highly recomment you to use a third party excel reading library. There are plenty of open source libraries available.

If your file is a Excel 2007 (.xlsx) file, I highly recommend using [EPPluse](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). It is also available as a [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/EPPlus).

Otherwise, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9155907/1174942) to find a few more libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Try to change your oledbconnection string as following format:

Code Snippet
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(
           @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\book1.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'");

Note: "IMEX=1;" tells the driver to always read "intermixed" (numbers, dates, strings etc) data columns as text. Note that this option might affect excel sheet write access negative.

Comment: in my case it is not working. The case is in a column first cell value is date and others are string and in an another column first cell value is string and rest are numeric. The rest values are still blank.

Answer (score 2):

MD.Unicorn's answer is not 100% correct. Your OLEDB provider uses a settings named `TypeGuessRows` to determine how many rows are read to decide the data type of a column. Unfortunately this setting cannot be specified in the connection string and must be changed in the system registry. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663674/1174942) question for more details.

Answer (score 1):

use IMEX=1 in connection string. hope it will resolve this issue..