# Import data from excel without using OLEDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

Hi all is it possible to load excel data without using `OLEDB`, I have written a code using the connection string as follows for `.xls and .xlsx`

`ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";`

`ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";`

In my system as `12.0` related `dll` is not present I got an error. So I would like to know whether there is any way to achieve my requirement rather than the general approach

Sample Code written

```
public void Method(string pFilePath)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(pFilePath, false))
        {

            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
            IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
            string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
            Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
            SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

            foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(0))
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell));
            }

            foreach (Row row in rows)
            {
                DataRow tempRow = dt.NewRow();

                for (int i = 0; i < row.Descendants<Cell>().Count(); i++)
                {
                    tempRow[i] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i - 1));
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(tempRow);
            }

        }
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    public static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument document, Cell cell)
    {
        SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
        string value = cell.CellValue.InnerXml;

        if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
        {
            return stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText;
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

But in `foreach (Row row in rows)` this condition I am getting an exception as `Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index`

Comment: You can try using OpenXML method


  `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx`

Comment: Hi `pratik` can you tell how I can load `2003` excel files too it is taking 2007 or 2010

Comment: This is limitation of using OpenXml method.  :( The only alternative to this is other third party tools suggested in the answers.

Comment: In the above code,date column reads as numeric e.g. Jan 2014 is read as 41640. Do you have any suggestion for it?

Answer (score 5):

I read from excel into a mysql database. Maybe not the nicest way todo it.
But here is my code:

```
 Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"\\xxxx\yyyy.xlsx");
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
        string Kund = "";



        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {


                if ((j == 1) && (i > 1))
                {
                    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(databas);

                    Kund = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
                }
                ...
            }
                ...
         }
           xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
```

You have to use `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

Answer (score 0):

I Was Reading some pretty heavy data from excel sheets a month ago and i used codeplex's ExcellReader which is a fine open source project for reading from excel. I hope it will help you too. just check it out..

Answer (score -1):

There are many third party components you can use for that. Please find quite a big list on NuGet:

https://nuget.org/packages?q=excel

Some of them don't require office to be installed (lookout for the keyword "standalone").

Not all are free and as such you should perform a proper software selection process to see what suits your requirements.

Comment: Hi if I need to Import both excel file and open office spread sheet data what should I use commonly

Answer (score -1):

So many suggestions for reading the XLS files are discussed on stack

[Read Excel 2003 & 2007 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155642/how-to-read-an-excel-file-in-c-sharp-without-using-microsoft-office-interop-exce)

Check this hope it helps.