# Missing COM reference tab in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to develop in VS2008, and I want to export a datatable to excel.  When I go to add the COM reference for Office, I am missing the COM tab. It is a .NET 3.5 for Windows Mobile.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid you don't have such a thing as "COM" in Windows Mobile. Am I right?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I was trying to do the export on the mobile side, but I guess I will have to do it on the desktop side when they sync the device.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to COM libraries on Windows Mobile.

There are other ways to create an Excel file. There are some open source libraries that are able to create Excel files without being dependent on Microsoft Excel COM libraries. They may be compatible with Windows Mobile.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp?rq=1) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155642/how-to-read-an-excel-file-in-c-sharp-without-using-microsoft-office-interop-exce). Maybe one of the answers help you.