# Excel Application on server not working if admin user is logged out

Tags: excel, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, excel-interop

I have a ASP.NET application which uses Microsoft intrope assemblies to read, write and modify excel files and it uses Excel 2013 on server machine. Application works fine if i am logged in to server machine as administrator but when i am logged out the application is unable to to initialize excel application. Here is the exception.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000401A)
```

Application is running on Windows Server 2008R2 with MS Excel 2013 32-bit I am not being able to figure out the reason of this behavior. Is this about COM objects security options or it has something to do with IIS permissions?

Answer (score 5):

The InteropServices class opens an (invisible) Excel instance to get its work done. Excel cannot run as a Windows service and needs to be instanciated by a logged on user.

**"Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."**
See this page for more information: [Office support: Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757)

If you still want to keep the interop service, try change it to run as an interactive user:

- Open Component Services (Start -> Run -> MMC comexp.msc /32)
- Find Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config -> Microsoft Excel Application
- Right click, choose properties
- Go to the Identity tab and choose Interactive user
- If this is not working, you can try to manually enter the user credentials

Of course, you could also switch to another framework to read the file. [SO: How to read an excel file in C# without using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155642/how-to-read-an-excel-file-in-c-sharp-without-using-microsoft-office-interop-exce)

Comment: currently I am facing this issue with Interactive User, I tried using Administrator credentials it solves this problem but then VBA addins don't work.

Comment: @AdilWaqar Are these add-ins integrated into your ASP.NET solution, or do you need them while you are 'actually working' with Excel?

Comment: no addin is not integrated in ASP.NET app, its  basically installed on server and run with Excel.

Comment: @AdilWaqar Try creating the folder: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop" Can't test it with your application, but it has solved a lot of problems with the Interop classes.

Comment: Both AppData and Desktop folders are there in SysWOW64 and system32

Comment: @AdilWaqar I've updated my post with information from the official Office support center. It may help you to decide on how to deal with server-side Office integration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after migrating from `2008r2` to `2012`. My solution:

- Find Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config -> Microsoft Excel Application
- Right click, choose properties
- Go to the Identity tab and choose This user (input user & password)